# AWS Lamba Failed to execute changes on GitHubRepo

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda

Setting up a new account with AWS. This is the first time I am seeing this error when creating an AWS Lambda Application:

> Failed to execute changes on GitHubRepo because: Forbidden (Service:
> Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID:
> Q4P4ABDSAFCC12H2; S3 Extended Request ID:
> JrhJOcSqro03RbV0v3HX5vHpDxVQFb8WZF+/MLOYIJeJ9HZB8OUYv/rFNYxmE/OM+ltRtrS3jFY=;
> Proxy: null) Failed to execute changes on PermissionsBoundaryPolicy
> because: Resource creation cancelled Failed to execute changes on
> S3Bucket because: Resource creation cancelled

Ultimately the lambda application is failing to create itself. The previous AWS account I have is established, hence, never have seen the former error before. Does anyone have any insight into the former? Clearly a connection issue with between AWS and Github somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. From AWS Support:

> With the help from the Code Star team, we investigated the issue and
> replicated the error message using a sample application and modified
> the runtimes and from the results the sample application works with
> lower Node.js runtime versions e.g., Node.js x16 however not with
> Node.js x18.
>
> I have reached out to our service team to investigate the issue
> further and will update you with the findings. Again, apologies for
> the inconvenience.

Something else to note for anyone that has issues with AWS Lambda... Run the command "node -v" within the buildspec.yml file and observe the output from the console/build logs. You'll quickly realize the node version being used for the Lambda app/container AWS is using will show version 10 regardless of choosing the node v16 runtime.

I actually had this former issue last year. At that point in time I was trying to create a Lambda app with a node v14 run time. The SAM CLI tool would invoke everything fine locally, however, one day the build/tests started failing on the AWS side during the build process... That was because whatever packages / code I added could not be interpreted correctly with v10, the version I ultimately found was being used/installed for the Lambda app.

The following screenshot shows recent output from the build logs depicting v10 being used, even though v16 was selected for the runtime. In fact, I don't even think you can select v10 for the runtime anymore. Only selectable options are v18, v16, and v14 as of now, where v18 is causing the original permission/forbidden errors...

[image]

Ultimately the work around I have within the buildspec.yml to obtain a later version of node is as follows:

[image]

Observing the "node -v" output again from within the console/build logs yields the following:

[image]